# C#: Generic Interface with different parameters

Tags: c#

Am trying to create an interface which will be used in two classes with different signature.
For example

```
public interface IEmp
{
    int EmpId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Emp
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public List < IEmp > Emps { get; set; }
}

public interface IEmpDict < T >
{
    T Fetch();
    void Add();
    void Remove();
}

public class Class1 : IEmpDict< Emp >
{
    public Emp Fetch() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void Add() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void Remove() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public class Class2 : IEmpDict< IEmp >
{
    public IEmp Fetch() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void Add() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void Remove() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public class EmpService
{
    private readonly IEmpDict< IEmp > _empDict;

    public EmpService(IEmpDict<IEmp> empDict)
    {
        _empDict = empDict;
    }

    public void AddEmp() { _empDict.Add(); }
    public void RemoveEmp() { _empDict.Remove(); }

    public void FetchEmp() { _empDict.Fetch(); }
}
```

I have the settings in the config. Based on the config settings, either class1 or class2 will be injected through the windsor castle. 
How can I inject the same in the EmpService - IEmpDict < IEmp or Emp >? 
Also, IEmp and Emp has different properties. In some cases, I need IsActive property if the Emp object has been instantiated. 
Is there any better approach to handle this implementation?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this design. `IEmp` and `Emp` seem to not be related in any kind of way, other than name. So it doesn't necessarily make sense for you to interchange them. Especially with `Fetch()` - one returns `Emp`, one returns `IEmp`, which appear to be *very* different things.

Comment: Yes. You're right. Two different things. Am working on the existing code. I would like to change the complexity with different approach. Basically, the class1 is implemented with normal dictionary and queue in place of list in the above example. Class2 for Redis Queue concepts. So that, If the code gets execute in the local which will instantiate the class1. If the same code gets execute in test / production environment which should instantiate the class2.

Comment: A return type of `void` on `EmpService.FetchEmp()` doesn't make sense. Think about what you need to do with this method and the design should become clear.

Comment: Its just the sample EmpService with placeholder. Not the real functionality.  The main question is how do I inject the class Emp or Interface IEmp in the EmpService IEmpDict < > depends on the config settings?